# How to administrate computer locked down with group policy?

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy

I have an XP machine where I want to lock it down and prevent what users can do on it.

I have disabled the control panel (along with a bunch of other stuff) using group policy.

This way the user accounts can't touch that stuff. But how do I administrate the computer?
Say I want to uninstall an application from the add/remove programs tool, or access anything else I have disabled on the administrator account?

I should mention, the computer is not on a domain.

Here's a good example:
I used the method [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323525) to restrict what programs can be run. But on the administrator account I need to have free access of what can be run so I can do maintenance tasks.

Comment: Are you connected to a domain or on a workgroup?

Comment: Are you the administrator and/or do the other users have administrator privileges? You stated you wanted to add/remove items on the administrator account?

Comment: @packets Not connected to a domain, but it is on a workgroup. There is only 1 administrator account on the computer and 2 user accounts that I want to lock down very tightly.

Comment: @Josh - **If there is an administrator account you should log into that to install applications**

Comment: @Ramhound Exactly. But on the limited accounts I can very easily go to the control panel/addremove programs and uninstall any programs I wish. I don't want the limited accounts to be able to do that, only the administrator.

Comment: @Josh No you can't, when you go to uninstall a program you will be prompted for an administrative username and password.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Well then something must be misconfigured because I'm not prompted for anything...

Comment: The uninstall won't fail till it actually attempts to perform an action that requires administrative privileges. Depending on the uninstaller [it may not happen until you click a menu or two in to the uninstaller](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NIAUd.png). You may get a error dialog like I got, or you may get the Run As dialog. It all depends on how the installer was written to handle a permissions failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many group policy settings can be set up to only apply to users if there members of a group.

Create a new group and put all of the users who you want to have restricted access to be members of that group. Then in Group Policy Management change the security filtering setting for the policy so it only applies to that group instead of all Authenticated users.

[image]

Comment: I believe this is for if the computer is connected to a domain? I should have mentioned, it's not.

Answer (score 2):

You can RDP into the computer to administer it.

Also note, most of the MMC Admin Tools can remotely connect to a computer.  Regedit, Perfmon, Disk management and Computer Management are among others. . .